# Woocommerce multisite seo and duplicate content

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-content, google-ranking, woocommerce

I have a client who runs a renting business. Actualy he's got an old wordpress where clients fills a form containing name, adress, the product they want to rent plus other optional infos. When he receive the form, he get in touch with the client and build a link for payment, then based on the client choices he delivers the product or the client go pick it at the selected area "store".

He rents his products in multiple areas in France (north and south + other areas in the future) and he asked me to find him a better solution.

My first idea was to build him a Woocommerce Multisite allowing him and his associates to manage separately clients and orders based on the client area, plus when a new area opens allowing him to build a website for that new area really fast, plus having separate stripe payment... The team of the south would manage their inventory stocks, reservations... That was for me the prettiest way.

His problem is that he rents same products in all those areas and that means they all share the exact same infos (name, picture, description... without the possibility of changing it) and he is scarred that my idea of using Multisites will kill his ranking because of duplicated content.

Plus, in my idea, all those website would have the same template. The only different infos would be contact address, inventory stock quantities and the page "Who are we".

I was so sure of my idea at the beginning but he's so scarred that he started to make me hesitate. I've since tryed few other options including woocommerce rental plugins but the problem of multiple areas (different inventory stock) is showing...

What do you guys think ? Will multisites creation with exact same content will be a ranking killer ? If so, what would you do in my case ?

Comment: If the product is exactly the same across multiple locations, why not have one site with all the core info, and list each location on its own separate "locations" page? On your "contact" page, you could invite users to contact the location nearest to them, and provide all the local contact infos. Perhaps even suggest one based on geolocation.

Comment: I think your client is wise to worry about ranking properly with multiple sites that all have the exact same content.

Comment: Great, that is what I had in mind if the first idea was wrong. I will create one page per stores and use a plugin that changes the menu (containing specific store infos such as contact, address...) to mimic another website. Thanks a lot for your time Maximillian.